# GMail API with JS AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, email, gmail-api

We use a common student information system to manage our school.  It is easily customized on the client side, and there are a couple of places where we'd like to trigger an e-mail when some action happens (form submission, page loaded, etc).  It is not possible to use server-side programming languages like PHP, ASP, or Java.

What we'd like to do is use an AJAX call to send the e-mail.  I have this working entirely in JavaScript, but I have to be logged in with the GMail account form which I want to send.  We need to this be authenticated once (or as long as the bearer token is valid) and then send off e-mails once the user action happens.

Since the client-side languages seem to be able to hit those endpoints and send an e-mail off without the sending account being "logged in" in a browser session, this seems possible to me.  Is it?

I also realize that creating a server-side script that uses GMail as an SMTP relay is an option, but many schools who use Google Apps For Education simply don't have a web server on site that can host such a script.  A client-side plugin is really what we want to build.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, just replace the **CLIENT_ID** value:

The scope for this is **readonly** but I you can change based on the operations you need to perform.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Your Client ID can be retrieved from your project in the Google
      // Developer Console, https://console.developers.google.com
      var CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';

  var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];

  /**
   * Check if current user has authorized this application.
   */
  function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
        'immediate': true
      }, handleAuthResult);
  }

  /**
   * Handle response from authorization server.
   *
   * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
   */
  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      // Hide auth UI, then load client library.
      authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
      loadGmailApi();
    } else {
      // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
      // clicking authorize button.
      authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
    }
  }

  /**
   * Initiate auth flow in response to user clicking authorize button.
   *
   * @param {Event} event Button click event.
   */
  function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: false},
      handleAuthResult);
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Load Gmail API client library. List labels once client library
   * is loaded.
   */
  function loadGmailApi() {
    gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', listLabels);
  }

  /**
   * Print all Labels in the authorized user's inbox. If no labels
   * are found an appropriate message is printed.
   */
  function listLabels() {
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.list({
      'userId': 'me'
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      var labels = resp.labels;
      appendPre('Labels:');

      if (labels && labels.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
          var label = labels[i];
          appendPre(label.name)
        }
      } else {
        appendPre('No Labels found.');
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
   * as its text node.
   *
   * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
   */
  function appendPre(message) {
    var pre = document.getElementById('output');
    var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
    pre.appendChild(textContent);
  }

</script>


  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="authorize-div" style="display: none">
      <span>Authorize access to Gmail API</span>
      <!--Button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
      <button id="authorize-button" onclick="handleAuthClick(event)">
        Authorize
      </button>
    </div>
    <pre id="output"></pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Source: [Gmail API - Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js)

Comment: I went down the path with that example, but the problem is, it prompts you for your Google account.  That would be fine, but we really need the email to happen silently without a person logging in.  Other APIs I've used allow you to obtain a bearer token using the ID and secret.  Is there a client-side method of doing something like that that we can adapt using JavaScript?  I'm not a novice developer, but I find the Google documentation to be very difficult to navigate.